# Installing AutoCAD vlx files with AutoCAD registry keys and Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, autocad-plugin

I have some vlx files to add to my *AutoCAD* folder. I would like to make install package with Inno Setup which will install my vlx files at post install.I got the registry key of AutoCAD 2014.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409
```

Please show me inno setup script for the above case.

Comment: Have a look here: http://otb.manusoft.com/2014/02/building-a-commercial-grade-lisp-plugin-installer-in-5-easy-steps.htm. The instructions pertain to lisp routines but you should be able to make the needed changes. I personally use `AcadInstall` but the problem is that this tool is no longer available on the internet.

Comment: I have got the link above before a week ago. And this is  a nice method. But I would like to know how I can use another way without using .arx files, but autocad registry key only because I have various autocad version registry keys. I don't want to use .arx files, but only autocad registry keys that I have mentioned above. Is that possible?

Comment: As mentioned, I used `AcadInstall` which does not need anything else. But the person stopped making it available so I don't know the legalities. If you go a Google for `AcadInstall` you will see it. Beyond that I can't help you myself.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: In some pages , I found that .lsp files are used instead of .arx for registry.And, I would like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [article](http://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=45075.15) which states:

> Below is a Inno Setup/Pascal code example of how to loop through AutoCAD versions and create the relevant LspLoad registry entries for an imaginary application called "MyCADApp".  It is purely to demonstrate the mechanism.  It is stripped down to just do 64bit ACAD on 64bit Windows to demonstrate the principle.
>
> Once you've got a handle on the pascal scripting, it should be relatively straight forward to modify/expand it to add tests for 32bit CAD on 64bit Windows and 32bit CAD on 32bit Windows and of course do similar for Bricscad.  All the additional functions you may require eg "IsWin64" can be found in the "Support Function Reference" in the Inno Setup Help files.

```pascal
procedure AddACADRegKey (Release: String); {eg 'R19.0 for ACAD 2013'}
var
  RunTimeNum: String; {eg '19'}
  AllProductID: TArrayOfString;
  ProductID: String; {eg 'ACAD-9001:409'}
  KeyPathShort: String;{eg 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\'}
  KeyPathLong: String; {eg 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.1\ACAD-9001:409\Applications\MyCADApp'}
  KeyStringShort: String; {eg c:\Program Files\MyCADApp\LspLoad.'}
  KeyStringLong: String; {eg 'c:\Program Files\MyCADApp\LspLoad.19.x64.arx'}   
  I: Integer;
begin
  RunTimeNum := Copy (Release, 2, 2);
  KeyStringShort := ExpandConstant('{pf}\MyCADApp\LspLoad.');
  KeyPathShort := 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\';
  if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKLM64, KeyPathShort + Release, AllProductID)
    then begin
      for I := 1 to GetArrayLength(AllProductID) do begin
        ProductID := AllProductID[I-1];
        KeyPathLong := KeyPathShort + Release + '\' + ProductID + '\Applications\MyCADApp';
        KeyStringLong := KeyStringShort + RunTimeNum + '.x64.arx';
        RegWriteDWordValue (HKLM64, KeyPathLong,'LOADCTRLS', 2);
        RegWriteStringValue (HKLM64, KeyPathLong,'LOADER',KeyStringLong);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

> An example of its useage - to test for ACAD 2012 and ACAD 2013 and add the registry entries triggered by an end installation event you would add the following code:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep=ssPostInstall
    then begin
        AddAcadRegKey ('R18.2');{ACAD 2012}
        AddAcadRegKey ('R19.0');{ACAD 2013}
   end;
end;
```

You will find additional information in that discussion thread.

---

Here is one example I am examining in the registry:

[image: Registry]

Now, the code I showed you creates those keys:

```pascal
RegWriteDWordValue (HKLM64, KeyPathLong,'LOADCTRLS', 2);
RegWriteStringValue (HKLM64, KeyPathLong,'LOADER',KeyStringLong);
```

Have you actually tried it? Why don't you manually add your VLX to the startup suite and then look at the changes made to the registry? Then you know what you need to do.

There is also information [here](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-70D60274-57E0-4B22-8D0C-3C7F212A7CAF) which I found with one search in Google:

## Load a .NET assembly

> After you have determined the build type of your .NET assembly, you must determine how it will be loaded into AutoCAD. A .NET assembly file can be loaded manually or with demand loading.
>
> - **Manually** - Use the NETLOAD command at the Command prompt or within an AutoLISP file.
> - **Demand load** - Define a key specific to the application you want to load when AutoCAD starts up. The key must be placed under the Application key for the specific release of AutoCAD that you want your application to be loaded in.
>
> The key for the application can contain the following keys:
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
> Description of the .NET assembly and is optional.
>
> **LOADCTRLS**
> Controls how and when the .NET assembly is loaded.
>
> - 1 - Load application upon detection of proxy object
> - 2 - Load the application at startup
> - 4 - Load the application at start of a command
> - 8 - Load the application at the request of a user or another application
> - 16 - Do not load the application
> - 32 - Load the application transparently
>
> **LOADER**
> Specifies which .NET assembly file to load.
>
> **MANAGED**
> Specifies the file that should be loaded is a .NET assembly or ObjectARX file. Set to 1 for .NET assembly files.

Comment: when I write code as above mentioned , it create registry. under 'HKLM/Software/autodesk/AutoCAD/ACAD-D001:409/applications/MyCADApp'. But I have no idea how to write code to add my files to this registry location. Please guide me.

Comment: @peteroo I have extended my answer for you.

Comment: Today I have found it how it works .And, thank you for your time spared for me, too. The page you shared is really nice.

Comment: wow, It is really simple I just used the inno setup built-in function '{reg:HKLM64\Autodesk\AutoCAD\.……………,……|{pf}\{#MyAppName}.It works for particular version.Maybe it will be needed pascal script [code] section if I would like improve for various versions.Anyway ,at least, I've found out what to do.*Really Simple* no need of .arx

Comment: But, Please tell me how to delete those registry entry from my computer, when I testing, I created many registries with various file names,j ust like MyCADApp, MyDuct,Dut_CAD,………………. . When I checked with window command line it created many . I don't know how to delete them because the Codes I used above are for adding registries , not including *delete* section when it is uninstalled.

Comment: That is a different matter altogether. You use REGEDIT to delete registry keys you don't need......... My answer explains how to create the correct keys and gives the information you need. If it works for you then please upvote and accept the answer. As mentioned, use REGEDIT to delete the obsolete keys (use caution!) and ask a separate question about how to get the uninstaller to remove the keys created with Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the autoloader bundle format. Then you don't have to mess with registry keys, and your Inno Setup script is just installing to the Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins folder under the user data folder, Program Data, or Program Files.

Comment: yes, this might be the next question to ask. If I don't bother to you, Can u please share me somethings about of autoloader. I just ask if u can.

Comment: hi there , I have already at this link, http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html  .Really thanks for next options

Comment: Yep that's the one. I had it on my clipboard but forgot to paste it.